# When trying to install Quickbooks API with Composer I get a "failed to open stream: no such file or directory" error

Tags: php, composer-php, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, package-managers

I'm trying to install the quickbooks API v3 using composer. When I use the command:

```
composer require quickbooks/v3-php-sdk
```

I get this back:

```
Using version ^3.2 for quickbooks/v3-php-sdk
./composer.json has been created
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing quickbooks/v3-php-sdk (v3.2.3): Downloading (100%)

Installation failed, deleting ./composer.json.
```

> ```
>   [ErrorException]
>   ZipArchive::extractTo(c:\Dropbox\Projects\Web\Websites\Instamation\wwwincludes/vendor/composer/034a1449/intuit-QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-b501
>   2d0\src\XSD2PHP\test\data\expected\ContactCompany\oasis\names\specification\ubl\schema\xsd\CommonAggregateComponents_2/AdditionalItemProp
>   erty.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
> ```

After doing some research, I've tried to run these commands without making any difference in the result:

```
composer clear-cache

composer dump-autoload

composer dump-autoload -o

composer update
```

I notice that there are both forward and backwards slashes in the path, which seems odd. Any ideas what is causing this error?

Comment: I faced that issue, You are right if we run that command on root then it work fine. I tried that, you can see detail attached screenshot. [Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHKWf.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a path issue. The path is too long. Composer is complaining about a path that is too long for PHP on Windows. Windows has a max path length (MAXPATHLEN) of 260 characters, similar example here: composer/composer#3755.

If you're not far over 260 (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx#maxpath) you might be able to rename your project to get around the limitation as a relatively simple "fix".

Comment: This was the issue. Sure enough. Changed the path to my website be about 8 characters shorter and it installed perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

since my first awnser didn't work,
try:

composer require  '. $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/quickbooks/v3-php-sdk';

also you must move it the document root or a folder on the document root. since that is where the web server only has access there.

Comment: That makes sense, but when I change it to a backslash, it doesn't seem to be able to find the package anymore. It tells me [InvalidArgumentException]
  Could not find package quickbooks\v3-php-sdk at any version for your minimum-stability (stable). Check the package spelling or your minim
  um-stability.

Comment: one of the things you have to keep in mind is that composer runs in the apache environment. one thing that makes things like this a pain on windows is that path names are different depending on what runlevel environment is used.  I'll give you examples on the windows uri identity issues: the standard UNC:  \\laptop\My Documents\FileSchemeURIs.doc is the same path as file://laptop/My%20Documents/FileSchemeURIs.doc and  file:///C:/Documents%20and%20Settings/davris/FileSchemeURIs.doc for  C:\Documents and Settings\davris\FileSchemeURIs.doc depending on windows ver. It should fallow the UNC  rules

Answer (score 0):

your error code:
   `ZipArchive::extractTo(c:\Dropbox\Projects\Web\Websites\Instamation\wwwincludes/vendor/composer/034a1449/intuit-QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-b501
      2d0\src\XSD2PHP\test\data\expected\ContactCompany\oasis\names\specification\ubl\schema\xsd\CommonAggregateComponents_2/AdditionalItemProp
      erty.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory`

because `wwwincludes/vendor/composer/034a1449/intuit-QuickBooks-V3-PHP-SDK-b5012d0` was a path generated in the php/apache enviroment which would point to the  `include_path =` statement in the phpini file.

So I would try changing the slash of the include path in the php.ini file.

If you are debugging this for composer, install a routine that will call the realpath() to correct mis-configured php paths from causing errors.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error while running this command `composer require quickbooks/v3-php-sdk` in cmd prompt.

> `Failed to download quickbooks/v3-php-sdk from dist: The archive may
>   contain identical file names with different capitalization (which
>   fails on case insensitive filesystems): ZipArchive::extractTo(): Full
>   extraction path exceed MAXPATHLEN (260)`

Then I changed my project name to smaller size, removed '-' from project name and finally I successfully installed it.